# Windows path/environment variable doesn't change for vim

Tags: windows, powershell, vim, path, environment-variables

When I write vim in powershell or cmd it say that "path/to/my/old/portable/vim80/vim.exe" does not exist. I have removed that vim long ago and have deleted its path from path variable.
I tried adding the path of the new portable vim to the path variable, but Windows still somehow finds the old path. I can't for the life of me figure out where Windows is reading that path. I looked under registry too to no avail. Even ran Ccleaner on the registry and still the problem persists.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you very much

TLDR; Somehow windows cannot forget the path of my old vim. I added the new path, but still it picks up the old one, how do I replace the old path? How is windows still finding the old path?

Comment: That's not something Windows does.  There must be a `vim.bat` or similar somewhere on your path, which is trying to run the missing executable.  Try `where vim` and see what that turns up.

Comment: It works. Please make this an answer so I can accept it as an answer :)